# Core Data: mutex/deadlock when changing two objects in different threads?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, mutex, deadlock

I've got two core data objects: an Organization and a Person which are linked together.

Is it a problem if I change them in different threads and save them both? So the threads are running in parallel:

Thread 1:
- load Organization with NSManagedObjectID
- make changes to the object
- save object

Thread 2:
- load Person with NSManagedObjectID
- make changes to the object
- save object

For me it seems as if I got a mutex because of this; not every time, but sometimes it happens. If that's the problem - what's the solution? :)

Thanks a lot!

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a problem if you are using the same NSManagedObjectContext. Core-Data, is not totally thread safe, NSManagedObjectID's are. On your background thread you must create a separate context with the same store and then save, which notifies the main thread when it is saved to merge the two contexts. You can control this merging by creating merge policies. So you can still do it but not as easily as hoped.

Comment: I do have separate NSManagedObjectContexts and only one PersistentStore. So I would assume that it should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: How are you merging the results? Have you set up notifications?

Comment: yes, notifications are set up. changes are merged with "    [mainContext performSelectorOnMainThread:mergeChanges withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];"

Comment: Is the problem on object creation or modification? With object creation when on separate threads there is no guarantee that the pair has been created yet. Are you using NSOperations or straight threads?

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the threads run parallel. CoreData is very efficient. Just do your data manipulations sequentially in the same thread and save once.

Core Data is designed in such a way that very rarely there will be the necessity to have more than one `NSManagedObjectContext`. One such context should always run on one thread at a given time.

**EDIT**

If that is not possible because you are relying on a web service etc., consider using `NSNotification`s and do the saving only on the main thread. (With `performSelectorOnMainThread`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not that easy. There are running async web-calls in the background - sometimes I get an organization: store it. Sometimes I get a customer - store that.

Comment: See my addition in the answer.

Comment: but how do I get the NSManagedObject to the main thread? If I fill the object in the background, I can't pass it to another thread, can I?

Comment: You do not get the NSManagedObject to the main thread, it is already there. You just need to get the info (from your web thread) *about* this new object to the main thread (e.g. via notification).